# Finding the intersect between a quadratic and line

Tags: python, numpy, plot, algebra, graphing

I am trying to find the intersect between a straight line and a quadratic curve, however the result I am getting appears to be imaginary although I don't see how this can be the case as I can see them intersect on real axes:

```
Import numpy
#quadratic coefficients



a,b,c = (-3.09363812e-04, 1.52138019e+03, -1.87044961e+09)

# y = ax^2 + bx + c



#line coefficients

m,d = (1.06446434e-03, -2.61660911e+03)

#y = mx + d



intersect = (-(b-m)+((b-m)**2 - 4*a*(c-d))**0.5)/(2*a)

print(intersect)
```

The output of this is 2458883.4674943495-107.95731226786134j

[image]

I am trying to find the intersect between the yellow curve over the blue points and the black dotted line

Comment: Are you asking a math question?

Comment: This is maths-related but I'm not sure if there is a problem with my code is the only thing.

Comment: Are you taking the square root of a negative number anywhere?

Comment: well the root part of the quadratic formula used when calculating the intersect is rooting a negative number.

Comment: You have a negative delta:  `(b-m)**2 = 2314594.4436156494`  and `4*a*(c-d) =  2314594.448077378`. Taking the difference yields `-0.004461728502064943`

Comment: If you do the calc by hand and get an equivalent result then you do not have a coding problem. When you tested your code with known inputs and compared the results against known valid results did it pass?

Comment: Quite a few results searching with variations `python find intersection of two curves` maybe there is an answer in them.

Answer (score 0):

The graphed curves you presented vs. your equations are not the same, and your equations do not intersect.

I rewrote some example code for you. `numpy` isn't needed, and an exact solution is possible.

```py
import math
import collections


def calculateIntersection(p, l):
  b = p.B - l.slope
  c = p.C - l.yInt

  discriminant = b**2 - (4 * p.A * c)

  if discriminant > 0.0:
    # 2 points of intersection
    x1 = (-b + math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0 * p.A)
    x2 = (-b - math.sqrt(discriminant)) / (2.0 * p.A)

    return discriminant, [(x1, l.slope * x1 + l.yInt), (x2, l.slope * x2 + l.yInt)]

  elif discriminant == 0.0:
    # 1 point of intersection
    x1 = -b / (2.0 * p.A)

    return discriminant, [(x1, slope * x1 + l.yInt)]
  else:
    # no points of intersection
    return discriminant, []


Line = collections.namedtuple('Line', 'slope yInt')
Poly = collections.namedtuple('Poly', 'A B C')

p = Poly(A=-3.09363812e-04, B=1.52138019e+03, C=-1.87044961e+09)
print(p)

l = Line(slope=1.06446434e-03, yInt=-2.61660911e+03)
print(l)

(discriminant, points) = calculateIntersection(p, l)

if (len(points) > 0):
  print("Intersection: {}".format(points))
else:
  print("No intersection: {}".format(discriminant))
```

Comment: Why are my curves different to my equations if the coefficients were determined using: coeffs = numpy.polyfit(x,y,2)?

Comment: also how would I still be able to get exact real solutions from this?

Comment: @OliverMoore sounds like there is more than 1 issue here. The first is that your polynomial/line expressions do not intersect, and the second is that you need code to find the intersection points. I've provided you with the second part of that. If you're having trouble with the fitting, please edit your post to show your original fitting.